# $n$-dimenstion space in geometric probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was solving the very well-known question : There is a stick with length 1. If I divide it into $n$ pieces which has the length $l_1<l_2< ... <l_n$, then calculate the probability of making a $n$-gon with those pieces. For any $n=3, 4$, then it's known that it could be solved with geometric probability by calculating the area on the 2D or 3D space. For example with $n=4$, we can calculate the volume which satisfies $x<\frac{1}{2}, y-x<\frac{1}{2}, z-y<\frac{1}{2}, 1-z<\frac{1}{2}$. This method can be generalized with any $n$ - calculating the volume which satisfies $x_1<\frac{1}{2}, x_2-x_1<\frac{1}{2}, ... x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}<\frac{1}{2}, 1-x_{n-1}<\frac{1}{2}$. But if $n>4$, it's impossible to visualize it on the space since the dimension is more than 3. How can I visualize it or calculate the volume of it? I proved that the answer is $1-\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ by the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I want to know how to deal it with geometric probability.